# Is there an alternate way to obtain licenses other than NX cash?

Tags: atlantica-online

The ***Patrol License*** (to view party details of monsters before battle) seems to be very useful. Is there some method to obtain this effect in-game (through items, player or mercenary skills etc.) without having to use the item shop?

If this answer can be generalized to **all** licenses, please provide that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go into town and see the markets. You can find in there licenses to buy for ingame money. Only thing, the permanent effect are not on all licenses and they dont come cheap.

[image]

Comment: It's been a few years since I played Atlantica, but I seem to recall that the teleport licenses (up to lvl 60 iirc) can be found through doing treasure maps. You could turn quite a nice profit selling the spares too.